# How can I figure out how many U.S. phonebooks contain a particular name?

Tags: data-request, tool-request, names

I have several names (first + last in combination) that are fairly common in the US, but I want to know how widely geographically dispersed they are.  So, for example, I can search at http://names.whitepages.com/ for "Michael Jackson," and can see that there are 9,364 phonebook listings for that name across the country.  But what I want to know is-- how many different phonebooks contain at least one listing for the name "Michael Jackson"?  Whitepages.com only seems to break it out by state, whereas I want to know about local phone directories.  Is there a way to figure this out without going through each listing by hand and examining the address data?

Comment: Do you care about the geography of the person for their listing or if they are in a phone book? Of course, many areas will include suburbs/MSAs in the phone book.

Comment: Great distinction-- for this question, I actually care about the phone book as the unit.  But if it's easier to focus on something like zip codes or city/town names, I would still find that useful.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. You might want to edit the question so others have a higher chance of understanding exactly what you're looking for. I'm not aware of any good set of data based on the actual printed book but wish you luck!!